# The functional differential equation : $f '(x) = a f(x/3)^2 + h f(x/4) + b$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, functional-equations, closed-form

Let $a,h,b$ be real numbers and $a$ is nonzero.

I want to solve the differential equation :

$$f '(x) = a f(x/3)^2 + h f(x/4) +b$$

In case no closed form solutions exist, I would like asymptotics.

If $b=0,h=0$ I guess all solutions are of the form

$$ c x^d $$

??

Assume $f(x) = c x^d$. Then

$$c d x^{d-1} = a c^2 (x/3)^{2d} = \frac{a c^2}{3^{2d}} x^{2d}$$

So $d-1 = 2d$ hence $d=-1$.
$- c  = 9 a c^2$, divide by $c$ assuming nonzero :

$-1 = 9 a c$ thus $c= \frac{-1}{9a}$.

---

***edit***

Just some thoughts :

I think it matters a lot if $a > 3/2$ or if $a < 3/2$.
This is based on taking higher derivatives and using the equation repeatedly.
In particular if $h^2 + b^2 $ is small but nonzero.

Also I was thinking that this might be related to a generalization of the Akra-Bazzi method.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method

None of these ideas are formal and solid for now, but just sharing.

Comment: This is incorrect, since the RHS will be dominated by the constant term $b$